# I keep getting the error "main.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase (experimenting with real time databases), and I can't figure out why it isn't recognizing firebase as a function.

I'm not exactly sure what to do, I'm relatively new to javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
            <script src='main.js'></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

```
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
 var config = {
    apiKey: "<apiKey>",
    authDomain: "<authDomain>",
    databaseURL: "<databaseURL>",
    projectId: "<projectId>",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "<messagingSenderId>",
    appId: "<appId>"
  };
// Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  console.log(firebase);

    firebase.database();

    var names = database.ref('names');

    var data = {
      name: 'Name'
    }

      names.push(data);
```

I want to be able to store names as data points with firebase, without any issues. Simple as that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To use the Firebase Realtime Database, you'll also need to include `firebase-database.js`. So add:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

See the list of all [available Firebase SDK libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries), specifically under the <kbd>from the CDN</kbd> heading (click to expand it).